# My manager is assigning me different tasks than he said he would

Tags: communication, manager

One of our projects failed that I mainly used to work on.  When it became evident, I asked my manager several times what I would be working on if it failed. The answer was I would help out with our new project where the manager really needed help (and was even saying we would maybe hiring for it).  Which was fine as I would be learning new things.  Including more of the things I did when I first started, because of the special skill set I have, which was not too heavy.

Now that that project failed, I was told that I would be doing mostly what I did when I first started.  Those tasks are very draining if done everyday all week long and generally speaking a step back. The manager also said that he is aware of the potential burnout but that I was the only one who had this skill set.  There is a budget to outsource some of it.

I am concerned that I will not be able to deliver and deal with the stress as it is really draining work. I was also looking forward to the new tasks but I am not sure if I will be assigned any of those now. He avoided to be specific so far what it will look like.

How can I go about this with the manager? I would really like to have a more balanced mix of old and new work tasks.

Answer (score 7):

The only sensible thing you can do here is to talk to your manager about it, including your concerns about whether you will be able to handle it.

However you need to be very careful in how you approach this subject. The manager may presumably assign his staff to tasks how they see fit and in order to support the business needs from time to time. They do not have to allocate work in way that enhances your life, though that is of course an excellent secondary goal for any manager of people. Their primary concern will be delivery of business requirements and if they can keep you happy at the same time then all well and good. But if they can't then unfortunately you will be the one to lose out. The manager probably already knows your concerns, fears and dislike for the allocated work, but they went ahead and assigned you anyway. That is, unfortunately, a role that management has to fulfil.

If you act as if the manager has betrayed you, or reneged on some kind of unwritten agreement that you would get new work, it will likely not cast you in a positive light.